# Autocomplete on .bash_aliases commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion, alias

I have a whole bunch of aliased commands in `.bash_aliases`

The most generic examples are

```
alias apt-update="sudo apt-get update"  
alias apt-upgrade="sudo apt-get dist-upgrade"
```

but then I also have

```
alias apt-install="sudo apt-get install "
alias a2avail="/etc/apache2/sites-available"
```

The first two are no issue, 
The second two I want to make the more powerful;

Specifically for `apt-install` I want autocomplete to work.

for a2avail I want to be able to type something like `sudo cp a2avail/default a2avail/new` and have it run as `sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/new`

are either of these two things possible?

Comment: There is a generic script for doing it to all alias here: http://superuser.com/questions/436314/how-can-i-get-bash-to-perform-tab-completion-for-my-aliases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding the following to your `~/.bashrc` should complete packagenames for your apt-install alias

```
_apt_install_complete() { 
    mapfile -t COMPREPLY < <(apt-cache --no-generate pkgnames "$2");
}
complete -F _apt_install_complete apt-install
```

As for a2avail, an alias will only work as the first word of a command, but you can use a variable.

```
a2avail=/etc/apache2/sites-available   # in ~/.bashrc

# then...
sudo cp "$a2avail"/{default,new}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of July 4th, 2017:

1. Install [complete-alias](https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias).
2. Add this line: `complete -F _complete_alias apt-install`.

You are done.